# Android file manager that can select by date?

Tags: file-management, android-app

Is anyone aware of an Android file manager that allows selecting files by date, preferably OSS?

I'm mounting my camera's SD card with a USB OTG adapter and want to copy all taken pictures starting from a given date, e.g. *select all pictures taken after 19.09.2023 and copy them to x.*

I tried Total Commander and several other apps as well, but most of them don't offer selecting at all or only allow selecting based on the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [MiXplorer](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/app-2-2-mixplorer-v6-x-released-fully-featured-file-manager.1523691/), free from XDA.

1. Order files by Date (Older) or Date (Newer).

   [image]
2. Select files by tapping the first file up to the desired range (here between July 2 and June 23). Long tap on the first file and last file to cover the range selection.

   It shows that 9 files have been selected. Tap the clipboard icon to copy the 9 files.

   [image]
3. Create a new folder where you want to copy. Here, it's the Test folder.

   [image]
4. Open the Test folder. Press the clipboard icon to reveal the details of the number of files to be copied.

   [image]
5. Click on the "COPY 9 files" to complete the copy action.

   [image]